# Oracle DBLink with username and password

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect to a second database via a dblink, but the password has not been included in the dblink.
Is there a way you can provide the password dynamically in the dblink when you call it

e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE@USERNAME/PASSWORD.DBLINK;
```

Thanks in advance.

K

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.

[image]

Database links created without username and password use authentication data of your current session.

Just create another database link with username + password included.

Comment: Thank for that. We ended up creating the new dblink in the end.